# Using System.Random over multiple data types - the Haskell way?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell in the most "Haskell way" possible, so I'm trying to avoid things like `do`s and `let`s that sort of obscure what's actually going on.

So I have a data type called `Org` that in is defined as so:

```hs
data Org = Org 
    { pos :: Pos2D
    , color :: Color           
    } deriving (Show)
```

where `Color` and `Pos2D` are defined as so:

```hs
-- Not actually defined like this, it's Graphics.Gloss.Data.Color
data Color = Color Float Float Float Float
data Pos2D = Pos2D Float Float
```

Now I've implemented `UniformRange` for `Pos2D` and `Uniform` for `Color` as so:

```hs
instance UniformRange Pos2D
  where
    uniformRM (Pos2D x1 y1, Pos2D x2 y2) g = Pos2D
        <$> uniformRM (x1, x2) g
        <*> uniformRM (y1, y2) g

instance Uniform Color
  where
    uniformM g = G.makeColor
        <$> uniformRM (0.0, 1.0) g
        <*> uniformRM (0.0, 1.0) g
        <*> uniformRM (0.0, 1.0) g
        <*> return 1.0
```

Given a tuple of `Pos2D` (representing the corners of the bounds), it will return a random `Pos2D` distributed uniformly between those. And for `Color`, it will return a random color with uniform R, G, and B values, but with a fixed alpha = 255 (1.0).

The question is now, how do I make an org?

```hs
randomOrg :: RandomGen g => g -> Org
randomOrg = -- ...
  where
    gen = mkStdGen 1337
```

The issue I'm having is that `uniformR` and `uniformM` take a `g` and return a tuple of `(a, g)`. So I'm not sure what the cleanest, most "Haskelly" way would be to actually chain these calls together to create the Org.

Any thoughts? Thanks,

**Edit:**

I know that I can do this:

```hs
randomOrg :: RandomGen g => g -> Org
randomOrg g = Org pos color
  where
    (pos, g1) = uniformR (Pos2D 0 0, Pos2D 720 480) g
    (color, g2) = uniform g1
```

But I'm not a fan of that for obvious reasons.

**Edit 2:**

Ok so after some thinking, I think the function I need might need to look something like this?

```hs
pUniform
    :: (Uniform a, RandomGen g)
    => (a -> b, g) -> (g -> (a, g)) -> (b, g)
```

But I'm not sure.

**Edit 3:**

Now I'm thinking a functor might be relvant:

```hs
(<$>) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So if we take some function `(a->b)` (which could be for example the `Org` constructor), and we have some `a` wrapped in the context `f`, which would be like `(a, g)` then we can produce a `b` wrapped in the context, which would be `(b, g)`. Seems right to me, but I'm not sure how to translate that into actual code.

Answer (score 4):

As outlined [here](https://alexey.kuleshevi.ch/blog/2021/01/29/random-interface/), the best way of doing this is by using the new monadic interface:

```
randomOrg :: StatefulGen g m => g -> m Org
randomOrg g = Org <$> uniformR (Pos2D 0 0, Pos2D 720 480) g <*> uniform g
```

Which you can then specialise to a pure stateful function:

```
randomOrg' :: RandomGen g => g -> (Org, g)
randomOrg' g = runStateGen g randomOrg
```

Though this approach is more general, so you can also run it e.g. in `IO` using mutable state:

```
randomOrg'' :: RandomGen g => IOGenM g -> IO Org
randomOrg'' = randomOrg
```

(Warning: these *should* work, but I haven’t double-checked it myself; please tell me if you find any lurking errors!)

Comment: In other words: you do this one in basically the same way you already did to implement `uniformRM` and `uniformM`.